# How to pass current url in the session using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, parameter-passing

I have a button, I want when I click on it, current url passes on the session. something like this:

```
$(".btn").click(function(e) {
     var url = window.location.href;
     // how to pass url in the session ?
});
```

Actually here is my structure:

```
// pageA.php
<input class="btn" value="set current url to session" />

<script>
   $(".btn").click(function(e) {
     var url = window.location.href;
     // how to pass url in the session ?
  });
</script>


// pageB.php
if (isset($_SESSION['url'])){
    $previous_url = $_SESSION['url'];
    header('Location: $previous_url');
}
```

Now I want to know how can I pass a javascript variable in the php session? Or in other word, how can I set `var url = window.location.href;` in the `$_SESSION['url']` ?

Comment: You can't access `$_SESSION` from outside PHP, but you could setup a third script and make a post request to it to have this url in the session. That's probably not good style though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send a Javascript value to PHP you'd need to use AJAX.

**JS :**

```
$(".btn").click(function(e) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    $.post('pageA.php', {url : url});
}
```

On your server, you would need to receive the url sent in the post like following :

**PHP :**

```
$_SESSION['url'] = $_POST['url'];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that directly because `PHP` is `server-side` and `JavaScript` is `client-side` and they simply can't "see" each other.

You can eg. pass your variable (url) to `PHP` using `Ajax` (eg. `jQuery.ajax()` method) and then save it in your session like any other user data.